# How to configure VMware in Windows 7 Home Basic?

Tags: windows-7, download

How can I configure VMWare in Windows 7, Home Basic?  Where can I download VMware? Is there a guide that shows me how to configure VMware?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a demo at their website, www.vmware.com 
There are also manuals, FAQs and whatnot on the site.  The documentation is quite thorough.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Player is also available for free from the website.
http://www.vmware.com/products/player/